# How can I generate a date that includes the time?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to generate a date with range but the time is not showing. The code is as follows:

```
def date_range(start, end, step: datetime.timedelta):
   while start < end:
   yield start
   start += step


  for d in date_range(
    start=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
    end=datetime.date(2019, 1, 15),
    step=datetime.timedelta(days=7),
    ):
    print(d)



  >>>2019-01-01
  >>>2019-01-08
```

The code shows the date only without the time. Why???

Comment: "date" objects only store dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `datetime.date()` which, according to the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) does not include time information - it just sets the hours/minutes/seconds to 0.

I think you want to use `datetime.datetime()` which does include time information.

See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) on `datetime.datetime()` for more information.